# Access jest.fn function inside another one

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have following case while writing jest unit test cases:

```
elasticsearch.Client = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        update: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return {}
        })
     }
});
```

Now, I want to do some expect on update function call. How can I access update function here in test case.

I can access elasticsearch.Client and its mock variable as elasticsearch.Client.mock. But how can I access similarly the update function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try moving the mock function for `update` to the outer scope:

```
const updateMock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return {}
});

elasticsearch.Client = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    update: updateMock
  }
});
```

Then you can use `updateMock` in your assertions. For example:

```
expect(updateMock).toHaveBeenCalled()
```